# Display google map in Index page using MVC5

Tags: c#, google-maps

I'm having this code and I want the location I'm searching to display in my index page not Online.

```
<form action="http://maps.google.com/maps" method="get" target="_blank">
    <input type="text" name="saddr" placeholder="Search your Place" />
    <input type="hidden" name="daddr" value="Durban,eThekwini municipality" />
    <input type="submit" class="styled-button-9" value="GET DIRECTION HERE" />
</form>
```

Comment: who is google man?? :o I hope it should be Google **map**!!

Comment: Sorry About that it Map

Comment: Can you please elaborate more about your problem??

Comment: You'd have to use the Google Maps iframe embed functionality. I'm not sure if there's an API call to build the embed code, but you can find the embed code (as HTML) via the gear at the bottom of a Google Map.

Comment: This is a embed google map and I wish it to display in the Index page when I'm searching a place and it redirect me online to the site of google map. I hope I'm clear will highly appreciate help.

Comment: Thank you Sir, I'm sorry for inconvenience I'm just new in this helpful forum.

Answer (score 0):

Use google places API. Login to api console and create your key and put into API.

Refer https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places